# rc522 RFID reader will only accept first tag after power up

Tags: arduino-uno, serial, lcd, rfid

I have an interesting problem using the Mifare rc522 device similar to http://www.ebay.com/itm/201415107836

I have this device connected to an arduino uno and drawing power from the 5V supply.
It reads cards and tags well.
Provided the card waved by it has previously been waved by it as the first card after power up.

It will recognise ALL the cards and tags I have with no problems but ONLY if each card has been at some time the FIRST card since the device was powered up.  Reset button does not help.  Once each card or tag has been used as the first after power up it will work every time thereafter.

I am using a very simple sketch which simply reads the RFID via serial link and then displays the data on an LCD.

Can anyone help explain this odd behaviour.
Is it something to do with the tags perhaps?
http://www.ebay.com/itm/201611365871 (bought from same seller who is, BTW very quick and cheap to mail parts)

I have tried running off a 12v supply (to the duino) and USB with same effect.  I have added a capacitor (47uf) across the power to the RFID - same issue.

```
/*
 Based on  LiquidCrystal Library - Hello World

 * LCD 4  RS pin to digital pin 12   Pin 
 * LCD 6  Enable pin to digital pin 11
 * LCD 11 D4 pin to digital pin 5       
 * LCD 12 D5 pin to digital pin 4
 * LCD 13 D6 pin to digital pin 3
 * LCD 14 D7 pin to digital pin 2
 * LCD  5 R/W pin to ground
 * LCD  1 VSS pin to ground
 * LCD  2 VCC pin to 5V

 */

// include the library code:
#include <LiquidCrystal.h>

char incomingByte = 0;
int cursorpos=0;

// initialize the library with the numbers of the interface pins
LiquidCrystal lcd(12, 11, 5, 4, 3, 2);
int detonate=10;
int shownumber=0;
void setup() {
  // set up the LCD's number of columns and rows:
  lcd.begin(24, 2);
  // Print a message to the LCD.
  lcd.print("Initialised");
  Serial.begin(115200);
}

void loop() {
  // set the cursor to column 0, line 1
  // (note: line 1 is the second row, since counting begins with 0):

  lcd.autoscroll();
   if (Serial.available() > 0) {
                // read the incoming byte:
                incomingByte = char(Serial.read());

                // say what you got:

                lcd.print (incomingByte, HEX);


        }

}
```

further edit:

I have now been able to get the thing to communicate using software serial - it seems to work out the baud rate quite well so despite the datasheet you are not limited to 115200 baud.  Still the same problem though as far as I can see it will now work with any 3 cards - any new card bumps one off the list of acceptables.  AAAARRRGGGGHHH

As requested, code change below - I basically lifted this directly off the arduino forum with changes only to make it work with an uno using software serial.  It does work, after a fashion but still the same problem with recognising only a few of the cards I have.

```
//emulate mega with software serial
#include <SoftwareSerial.h> 
SoftwareSerial mySerial(2, 3); 

unsigned char command, devnull;
unsigned int returnLength;

void setup() {

Serial.begin(9600);
mySerial.listen();
  Serial.println("Waiting for Card\n");
mySerial.begin(9600);

  mySerial.write(0x02); //Send the command to RFID, please refer to RFID manual

}

void loop() {
   if (mySerial.available())
    {
      Serial.print("\n\rCARD SERIAL: ");
      for (unsigned int i=0; i<4 ;i=i){
        //Serial.print("2");   
        if (mySerial.available()) {
            //Serial.print("\n\ri is: ");Serial.print(i);Serial.print(" ");
            Serial.print(mySerial.read(),HEX); //Display the Serial Number in HEX
            i++;
          }
        }

       Serial.println("\n\rRead Card Make...");
       mySerial.write(0xAB);mySerial.write(0x02);mySerial.write(0x01);

       Get_Reply();

       mySerial.write(0x02); //Send the command to RFID, please refer to RFID manual
    }

}void Get_Reply() {
       while (!mySerial.available());
       devnull = mySerial.read();
       while (!mySerial.available());
       returnLength = mySerial.read() - 1;

       for (unsigned int i=0;i< returnLength;i=i){
         //Serial.print("2");
         if (mySerial.available()) {
            //Serial.print("\n\ri is: ");Serial.print(i);Serial.print(" ");
            Serial.print(mySerial.read(),HEX); //Display the Serial Number in HEX
            i++;
          }
        }
}
```

Comment: Please post the sketch. It might have an issue even if simple.

Comment: You could try to run some example sketches, to see if they have the same problem.

Comment: Thanks.  Added code as requested.  It's a head scratcher as there is no memory usage intended.

Comment: Can you try to send the in coming bytes to your PC via USB and possibly take out the LCD code? Or directly connect to the rfid-board using an USB-UART cable? It may be that the code is working just fine, but the cursor leaves your LCD screen or that the LCD gets stuck in some kind of loop.

Comment: *It will recognise ALL the cards and tags I have with no problems but ONLY if each card has been at some time the FIRST card since the device was powered up.* - sounds like a problem with the reader. Maybe you need to acknowledge that you have read the card, or something?

Comment: Thanks nick - was thinking along the same lines.  It reports a code for every tag every time but only if that tag has at some point been the first tag presented after power up.  I have thought it may be writing to the tags but there is very little info on this particular unit.  Should have bought a better one but have been enjoying the challenge.

Comment: I cannot use USB to get the info from an uno as the card reader uses the serial and requires 115200 baud which exceeds softwareserial capability.  I may try a mega, but that is overkill for all the projects I have in mind so I don't have one of those right now.

Comment: Update the code in your question.

Comment: My guess is that you have to do this in two steps, i.e. 1) read from mySerial to a buffer, 2) write to Serial.